# Spamassasin not checking SPF - Perl error?

Tags: centos6, perl, spamassassin, webmin, virtualmin

Getting lots of email spoofing spam from our own domains to my Webmin installation using Spamassasin, the error im receiving when debugging spam is as follows:

> May 19 09:33:45.959 [15233] dbg: spf: cannot load Mail::SPF::Query module: Can't locate Mail/SPF/Query.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/local/lib/perl5 /
>   spf: one of Mail::SPF or Mail::SPF::Query is required for SPF checks, SPF checks disabled

This is allowing a lot of mail spoofing to come through.

My system is CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

How can i go ahead and install this module so spamassasin can make use of it?

Answer (score 2):

It appear you don't have SPF installed. You should be able to install it using the command:

```
sudo yum install perl-Mail-SPF -y
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue with a clean `SpamAssassin 4.0.0` installation on a fresh `Debian 12`.
The error i got (deep in manual spamassassin call debug output) was:
`dbg: spf: cannot load Mail::SPF: module: Can't locate Mail/SPF.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Mail::SPF module)`

The following solved the problem:

```
apt install libmail-spf-perl
```

Not sure why such a fundamental part was missing in a clean install of SpamAssassin. The first visible result in spamassassin was that any SPF checks were missing in the `X-Spam-Status` header (part `tests=` - no `SPF_` value was there). There was no other "visible" indication of why the SPF checks were not evaluated at all.